# is there a python function i could use to take live data and feed to my model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, trading, algorithmic-trading

```
class KNNStrategy(Strategy):
    price_delta=0.05
    kk=Strategy.closed_trades
    def len(self):
        return len(self.closed_trades)
    def init(self):
        self.last_high = 0
        self.last_low = 0
        self.knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=2)
        self.knn.fit(x_train, y_train)
        self.forecasts = self.I(lambda: np.repeat(np.nan, len(self.data)), name='forecast')
        self.buy_signal = None
        self.sell_signal = None
        self.bar_count = 0
        
        
    def next(self):
        
        if len(self.data) < len(x_train):
            return

        
        high, low, close = self.data.High, self.data.Low, self.data.Close
        current_time = self.data.index[-1]

        current_point = data.loc[current_time-pd.Timedelta(minutes=60):current_time].iloc[-1]
        

        current_macd=calculate_macd( data['Close'])
        current_macd_last = current_macd[-1]
        current_BB=calculate_bollinger_bands( data['Close'])
        current_UB=current_BB['UB']
        current_UB_last = current_UB[-1]
        print(current_UB_last)
        current_LB=current_BB['LB']
        current_LB_last = current_LB[-1]
        current_rsi=calculate_rsi(data)
        latest_rsi=current_rsi[-1]
        lev = calculate_pivots_support_resistance(data)
        current_pivot = lev['pivot']
        current_r1 = lev['r1']
        current_s1 = lev['s1']
        current_r2 = lev['r2']
        current_s2 = lev['s2']
        current_r3 = lev['r3']
        current_s3 = lev['s3']
        latest_pivot = current_pivot[-1]
        latest_r1 = current_r1[-1]
        latest_s1 = current_s1[-1]
        latest_r2 = current_r2[-1]
        latest_s2 = current_s2[-1]
        latest_r3 = current_r3[-1]
        latest_s3 = current_s3[-1]
        X = pd.DataFrame({
            'MACD': [current_macd_last], 
            'RSI': [latest_rsi], 
            'UB': [current_UB_last], 
            'LB': [current_LB_last],
            'Pivot': [latest_pivot],
            'R1': [latest_r1],
            'S1': [latest_s1],
            'R2': [latest_r2],
            'S2': [latest_s2],
            'R3': [latest_r3],
            'S3': [latest_s3]
        })
        print(X)
        
        forecast = self.knn.predict(X)[0]
        self.forecasts[-1] = forecast
        print(forecast)
        upper, lower = close[-1] * (1 + np.r_[1, -1]*self.price_delta)

        if forecast == 0 and self.position.size == 0:
            self.buy(size=.2,sl=self.last_high)
        elif forecast== 1 and self.position.is_long:
            self.position.close()
        elif forecast== 1 and self.position.size == 0:
            
            self.sell(size=.2, sl=self.last_low)
        elif forecast == 0 and self.position.is_short:
            self.position.close()   
        

data=yf.download('EURUSD=X', start='2022-03-30',interval='1h')

bt= Backtest(data, KNNStrategy, cash=10000)

bt.run()
```

i'm trying to take the current time data point and calculate the indicators and feed one row at a time to my knn model, it's like doing live trading but the data dont change it generate one row and makes one trade , i think my indicators are not dynamic , and i can't feed current_point to indicators because my indicators use privious data and current point is one row.

Comment: You need to compute the indicators beforehand and add it to your input layer. Each row will then have O, H, L, C, volume, indicatorA, indicatorB, etc...

Comment: @Simo Kial I provided several sources of stock data in my answer. But out of the three `webull` provides the fastest updates (whereas for example alpaca's data streams every minute or so). All three are free but only Yahoo finance provides data without having to make an account.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `alpaca`'s API, calling `get_bars` function returns OHLCV info:

```
!pip install alpaca-trade-api
import alpaca_trade_api as alpacaapi
alpaca = alpacaapi.REST('ID', 'PASSWORD', 'https://api.alpaca.markets')
import numpy as np
stonk_names = ['AAPL', 'AMZN', 'MSFT']
alpaca.get_bars = np.vectorize(alpaca.get_bars)
df = alpaca.get_bars(stonk_names, '1Min', limit=1)
```

or we can use `webull`'s API (which I think is much better than `alpaca`'s and which also has data for options trading):

```
import pandas as pd
!pip install webull
import webull
from webull import webull
wb = webull()
my_wb_account = wb.login('my_email@gmail.com', 'password')
stonk_name = 'AAPL'
timeframe = '1'
period = '1'
data = wb.get_bars(stock=stonk_name, interval='m' + timeframe, count=int((390*int(period))/int(timeframe)), extendTrading=0)
data = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Outputs:

```
                             open    high     low   close      volume    vwap
timestamp                                                                    
2023-03-31 09:31:00-04:00  162.36  162.55  162.13  162.52   1298214.0  162.37
2023-03-31 09:32:00-04:00  162.51  162.60  162.38  162.41    207786.0  162.38
2023-03-31 09:33:00-04:00  162.41  162.50  162.22  162.50    198219.0  162.38
2023-03-31 09:34:00-04:00  162.50  162.76  162.48  162.70    260795.0  162.41
2023-03-31 09:35:00-04:00  162.70  163.03  162.70  163.03    395259.0  162.49
...                           ...     ...     ...     ...         ...     ...
2023-03-31 15:56:00-04:00  164.66  165.00  164.66  164.92   1047197.0  163.61
2023-03-31 15:57:00-04:00  164.92  164.97  164.86  164.94    666129.0  163.63
2023-03-31 15:58:00-04:00  164.94  164.94  164.81  164.89    615678.0  163.65
2023-03-31 15:59:00-04:00  164.88  164.97  164.81  164.94    895879.0  163.68
2023-03-31 16:00:00-04:00  164.94  165.00  164.71  164.90  14555382.0  164.13
```

Either way, it requires making an account with the brokerage (in order to login). Many brokerages (including `alpaca` and `webull`) offer paper trading accounts as well.

If we want access to data without having to setup an account with a brokerage, we can use YahooFinances's `yfinance`:

```
import yfinance as yf
data = yf.download('SPY', start='2023-03-31', end='2023-03-31')
```